# Drool kie workbench integration with my web application

Tags: drools-kie-server

I want to integrate drool Kie UI to edit my rules from UI side.
I have already many rules in my web project.. please let me know how i can open those in UI to edit and again after build and deploy how it will update in my web application repository.

Comment: We need to know more about what you have tried so far and how it failed to meet your needs.

Comment: i have installed kie workbench  in my server. now i want to edit my existing rules from my webapplication through this new kie UI.